# remote phpmyadmin can't login but mysql client can

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've got two servers: Web and MySQL, both on Ubuntu 12.04 x64

On Web is setup a phpmyadmin installation and nginx etc.
On MySQL is setup a mysqsl installation

When I run mysql --user=user --host=MySQL.hostname --password, from Web, I can connect just fine to the MySQL server

But when I try to connect via phpmyadmin, ***it does not work. why?***

User is not root

In the /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file (which I copied from the sample), I have this:

```
/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'MySQL.hostname';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

On the MySQL server, I have it setup to bind to 0.0.0.0 and I have user permissions for this user on 'localhost' and '%' (remember- I do connect just fine via mysql client)

(note: MySQL.hostname is actually a resolvable hostname, just using this here for example)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: from phpmyadmin it's a can't login... but I believe that's the same error if it can't connect?

Comment: Did you try changing the extension to 'mysql'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK the answer is simple, even though the main files reside in /usr/share/phpmyadmin, the config is actually loaded in /etc/phpmyadmin/

Changing config.inc.php there did the trick :)

Comment: This behavior is caused by the distribution policy; all configuration files belong in a particular place (/etc/), most of the rest of the package goes in /usr/share/, and so on. With the official phpMyAdmin distribution, you're right that config.inc.php would go with the other files, but most distribution's packages spread files all over the file system. Nice work getting it going.

Comment: This worked for me also on CentOS 6.x. Was fiddling around for ages in the completely wrong config.inc.php until I found this....

Comment: Changing config.inc.php to what?

Comment: @JimB, Keep the file name. Change the contents of the file.

Comment: can you explain which config changes allowed you to connect from a remote ? what are the content changes you refer to ?

Comment: The /phpadmin/setup interface supposedly saved changes, but it never actually did in the /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php file, so I had to do it manually.  Perhaps it was a permissions thing with saving, although no error messages were given.  Stupid

Answer (score 1):

As this topic come up as one of the first searchresults, my findings could help someone else.

I had the same symptoms:
login possible from command line with #mysql -u root -p
login fails thru phpmyadmin without error shown.

For me the problem disappeared after installing ntp and syncing time

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. I checked the error log of the web server[Apache] and found out that the server was full. no space even for writing into access.log file.
Here is what I have seen in the log file
No space left on device: [client xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx] AH00646: Error writing to /var/log/apache2/access.log, referer: https://server/address/phpmyadmin/
I freed some space and worked.