# Access denied, root

Tags: phpmyadmin, configuration-files

I've recently installed phpMyAdmin.  Attempting to connect via my browser I get this error page:

"Error

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

phpMyAdmin was unable to read your configuration file!
This might happen if PHP finds a parse error in it or PHP cannot find the file.
Please call the configuration file directly using the link below and read the PHP error message(s) that you receive. In most cases a quote or a semicolon is missing somewhere.
If you receive a blank page, everything is fine.

./config.inc.php"

It looks to me that the basic problem is that phpMyAdmin is simply not able to access the config file, because when I click on the config.inc.php link on the error page, I get a message saying "Starting to parse config file..." but then nothing happens after that and it doesn't display anything else on the screen.  So it appears that phpMyAdmin is hanging up when it tries to read the file.

I have the config.inc.php file in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin which is globally-readable, and it is owned by root.apache. I haven't been able to figure out why phpMyAdmin can't read this file.  Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Also, does your webserver or PHP error log contain any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the path /usr/share/phpMyAdmin which many package managers use for the path to install the phpMyAdmin source files -- but due to policy, put the configuration in /etc/phpmyadmin. Did you install with a package manager? Probably your config.inc.php belongs there.

See [remote phpmyadmin can't login but mysql client can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934016/remote-phpmyadmin-cant-login-but-mysql-client-can/19936405#19936405) for a bit more on the matter.